# how to measure the musical length of a stream in music21?

Tags: python, music21

i want to measure the musical lenght of a music21 stream. the stream is a short midi file exported from my DAW.

```py
sequence = converter.parse('In MIDI/input.mid')
measures = sequence.getElementsByClass(stream.Measure)
num_measures = len(measures)
print(f"The Stream has {num_measures} measures.")
```

will output

```
The Stream has 0 measures.
```

What am i doing wrong?